# How to sum values in an iterator in a PySpark groupByKey()

Tags: python, apache-spark, iterator, pyspark, rdd

I'm doing my first steps on Spark (Python) and I'm struggling with an iterator inside a `groupByKey()`. I'm not able to sum the values: My code looks like this:

```
example = sc.parallelize([('x',1), ('x',1), ('y', 1), ('z', 1)])

example.groupByKey()
```

```
x [1,1]
y [1]
z [1]
```

How to have the sum on `Iterator`? I tried something like below but it does not work

```
example.groupByKey().map(lambda (x,iterator) : (x,sum(iterator))
example.groupByKey().map(lambda (x,iterator) : (x,list(sum(iterator)))
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply `mapValues` with `sum`:

```
example.groupByKey().mapValues(sum)
```

although in this particular case `reduceByKey` is much more efficient:

```
example.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

or

```
from operator import add

example.reduceByKey(add)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do it in this way:

```
wordCountsGrouped = wordsGrouped.groupByKey().map(lambda (x,y):(x,map(sum,y))).map(lambda (x,y):(x,y[0]))
```

It is a bit late but i just found this solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

To add on @zero323's answer, another solution would be :

```
example.groupByKey().map(lambda (x,iterator) : (x,len(iterator)))
```

Comment: Are you sure this works as intended? From my understanding, you're simply creating a lambda function that lists X variables and the length of the iterator, this doesn't sum them up. I'm learning spark and going through a tutorial at the moment. The above statement simply pairs X and the length of an iterator. It doesn't sum the iterator.